# C# simple Linq to XML query returning only 1 result

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a project handling simple xml. BUt my LINQ query doesn't work fine. If you would help me. i kind of stuck i have similar project working fine.
Below my code to handle C#

```
void RecordsDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
        }
        else
        {
            XElement xml = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
            String bandKey = bandID.Text;

            IEnumerable<XElement> musicXml = xml.Elements("band");

            Boolean foundRecords = false;

            foreach (XElement band in musicXml)
            {
                if (band.Attribute("bandID").Value == bandKey)
                {

                    ResultsListBox.ItemsSource = from song in band.Descendants("songs").Descendants("song")
                                                 select new Song
                                                 {
                                                     Name = song.Attribute("name").Value,
                                                     Sum = song.Attribute("sum").Value,
                                                     Number = song.Attribute("number").Value
                                                 };
                    foundRecords = true;

                    break;

                }
                else
                {
                    foundRecords = false;
                }
            }

            if (foundRecords)
            {
                if (ResultsListBox.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Music Band songs Record(s) Found!" + ResultsListBox.Items.Count);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You do not have any Movie Session!");
                ResultsListBox.ItemsSource = null;
            }


        }
    }
```

and my xaml code

```
<ListBox Background="Black"  Height="472" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,148,0,0" Name="ResultsListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" SelectionChanged="ResultsListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="120">
                        <StackPanel Width="350">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sum}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

my class code

```
namespace MusicRateMobile
{
public class Song
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Sum { get; set; }

    public String Number { get; set; }
}
}
```

and my xml code

```
<music>
 <band bandID="1" name="Gorillaz">
  <songs>
   <song name="Feel Good" sum="4" number="1">
   </song>
  </songs>
 </band>
 <band bandID="2" name="Eminem">
  <songs>
   <song name="Mockingbird" sum="4" number="1"/>
   <song name="Slimshaddy" sum="4" number="1"/>
  </songs>
 </band>
</music>
```

Comment: Your XAML code is not so relevant, show (a piece of) the XML.

Comment: And be clear about what "doesn't work fine". We need expected vs actual outcomes.

Comment: At least you should have made it clearer on what you want and how your LINQ query didn't work?

Comment: sorry, guys. i think i have done not very clear, cause it is very late in night. for xaml, i just have textbox and button above listbox. for my error, my querry returning only one result, but my xml has a two inside. ResultsListBox.Items.Count tells that it is only one item, but according to xml, should be more

Comment: I have edited document, my xml now in the document.

Comment: When bandKey == "Gorilla" then there's only 1 result.

Comment: no, bandKey == 2, because i am using a BandID, was getting only one result. Now is all fine, i have restarted visual studio. Thanks, Holterman for your time to read my bad structured question)

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultsListBox.ItemsSource = from song in band.Descendants("song")
                             select new Song {
                                              Name = song.Attribute("name").Value,
                                              Sum = song.Attribute("sum").Value,
                                              Number = song.Attribute("number").Value
                                             };
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it doesnot solve the problem. My xml has two songs in bandID=2, but ListBox receives only 1 result, no second second song="slimshaddy"

Comment: @AstarBekturov I'm not very familiar with how `DataSource` is treated in `WPF`, I mean if in `winforms` the `LINQ` query should be appended with `.ToList()` (or something similar). Have you tried it yet?

Comment: i will try to do something like that, not sure how it works, yet. Thank you, anyway

Comment: stupid thing i have almost same code in another project and it works(

Comment: @AstarBekturov even no need to append `ToList()`? If so, I've leaned a new difference between `WPF` and `winforms`.

Comment: yes, worked without append toList(). even above example working fine, but i getting only first result of xml, maybe my file is not updating in server side or something like this.

Comment: I have restarted my visual studio, now evertyhing works fine. Thank you, @king King. Sry that my reputation is low